# Get dates with no entries in database

Tags: mysql, database, date

I have a database (MyISAM) that stores user inputed entries for each day. It's basically a worksheet for employees where they enter what they did on a particular day.

I need to get the days in which users did not enter any entries so i can mark that day as a vacation day.
More exactly, i need to get a table like

```
    Date           User 
    20-11-2013     test1
    20-12-2013     test1
    20-12-2013     test2
```

How exactly do i go about doing this?

Comment: do you have an entries column?

Comment: yes, there is a column for entry start time and one for entry end time

Comment: build another table with all the dates in it for comparison, or use ddd date formats an select the nbumbers < 365 to do the comparison

Comment: Choices: 1. sproc, 2. UNION, 3. calendar table, 4. application level code

Comment: either calendar table or aplication level code considering i'm outputting the data in php

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range.
Haven't got a full solution (yet), but I'm thinking `LEFT JOIN` this to your entries table, or join with a `COUNT` on the entries table with a group by on Date and User, and you can easily pick out those dates with no matching records.